# Align marginpar with beginning of paragraph

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar

Is there a way to align a marginpar with the beginning of a paragraph, without cluttering the text of the paragraph?

If I do the following, the marginpar lines up with the last line of the first paragraph.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur scelerisque purus vitae nisl lacinia at volutpat sapien bibendum. Sed mollis ultricies arcu non posuere.
\par
\marginpar{Praesent nulla arcu.}Proin neque ante, placerat in laoreet quis, egestas sit amet leo. Mauris vestibulum cursus elit et vulputate. Cras congue nulla vitae tortor mattis porttitor.
\end{document}
```

Moving the marginpar after the first word of the second paragraph produces the desired effect, but clutters the source document (especially with longer marginpars). Is there a way to achieve both?

Comment: `\hspace{0pt}\marginpar{...}` at the front of the paragraph should do the job

Comment: Indeed. Thank you. If you answer again (not in comment) I can assign it "correct answer". In the meanwhile I answer it myself to save other people time.

Comment: Ok, seems I can not answer my question within 24 hours and I can not close the question either...

Comment: the delay is to get multiple opinions.  In some cases the best answer is not always the first answer that works.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`\leavevmode\marginpar{...}` at the front of the paragraph should do the job<sup>1</sup>.

Minimal example

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\leavevmode\marginpar{Aligned marginline}
\kant[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

1:  See [Function and usage of \leavevmode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22852/function-and-usage-of-leavevmode) for more information about `\leavevmode`.

Comment: Why not `\leavevmode` instead of `\hspace{0pt}?

Comment: @egreg, I got the advise from someone else. Is there any particular difference?

Comment: `\leavevmode` leaves no trace of itself if already inside a paragraph, while `\hspace{0pt}` does.

Comment: It might also be useful after `\marginpar` to append `\ignorespaces` to clear justified space between words.