# why does \hspace{0pt} produce a space at the beginning of the paragraph together with \marginpar?

Tags: spacing, marginpar

Similar situation as in [Align marginpar with beginning of paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16141/align-marginpar-with-beginning-of-paragraph).

Basically I need to align the margin note to the beginning of the paragraph, and I'm putting the `\marginpar` command before the first word of the paragraph. This can be done by adding a `\hspace{0pt}` before the `\marginpar` command.

However, I'm also setting `\parindent` to `0pt`, and this will produce a space at the beginning of the paragraph. Currently I'm using something like `\hspace{-0.15cm}` as a hack to fixed this problem, but it's not very pretty, any better solutions?

(I have tried the `marginnote` package, but there are still a few problems. It automatically aligns the margin note to the first line of the paragraph, except when there is a page break and the margin note will appear on the previous page. The longer margin notes will also overlap.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you never need the optional argument to `\marginpar` you can use `\initmarginpar` defined as

```
\newcommand{\initmarginpar}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{#1}\ignorespaces}
```

Otherwise always remember to protect the end of line with a comment character:

```
\marginpar{Margin note}%
Start of the paragraph...
```

I believe that `\leavevmode` (or even more `\quitvmode`) is much better than `\hspace{0pt}`.

Comment: Thanks, both the command \ignorespaces and the comment character, or even starting the text immediately after the closing brace of \marginpar solves the problem. I try to make the source more readable by using spaces and empty lines a lot, but maybe I shouldn't after all...

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\begin{document}
\hspace{0pt}\marginpar{blub}Some text

Some Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the problem was that I started a new line after the \marginpar (leaving a space after the closing brace also cause the same problem), putting a comment at the end of the line, as suggested in the other answer also solve the problem. Perhaps it has something to do with the way LaTeX parse things, I definitely need to learn more about how LaTeX works...