# Vertical align a marginpar with the first line of a paragraph

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Align marginpar with beginning of paragraph](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16141/align-marginpar-with-beginning-of-paragraph)

Is there a way to vertical align a marginpar with the first line of a paragraph, instead of the last?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx, I think your question is a repeat of the one linked in the comment above, if you confirm the answers there solve the problem  this question can be closed as we try to avoid duplicates. If it doesn't solve your problem please add a small complete document to your question that demonstrates the problem.