# Margin notes aligned with top of paragraph

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar

When I put a margin not at the beginning of a paragraph, latex assumes it is at the end of the previous paragraph. I'd like the margin note to align with the top of the paragraph it is in. [It seems](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/16141) this is possible with individual notes. How do I achieve that globally without having to put the margin note inside the text of the paragraph. Follows the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\marginpar{some note} This is what it should look like in the source code. \lipsum[1]

\marginpar{another note} Good in source code, but bad in PDF. \lipsum[2]

Cluttered\marginpar{yet another note}source code, but produces desired effect in PDF. \lipsum[3]

\leavevmode\marginpar{individual solution to be implemented globally} Would be nice, you know. \lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

EDIT:

I tried with a `\newcommand`:

```
\newcommand*{\annot}[1]{
    \leavevmode\marginpar{#1}}
}
```

but

```
\annot{margintext}Text.
```

produces an extra indentation, so this is not the end of the solution. Actually this is the one that needs fixation.

Comment: Try adding a `%` at the end of your `\newcommand*` line, so that TeX sees no space before `\leavevmode`

Comment: Remove the blank space after the closing `}` of the `\annot` invocation.

Comment: I always wondered why people put a space after their newcommand and environments and stuff. I always thought it was to prepare comments or something bland... well, thanks.

Comment: Alternately, you can define `\newcommand*{\annot}[1]{\leavevmode\marginpar{#1}\ignorespaces}` which will ignore the spaces after the closing of the argument

Comment: Oh, wow, you opened up a whole new world for me. I will put them `%` everywhere, from now on!

Comment: That's a very bad idea...

Comment: @TeXnician Are you talking to me?

Comment: Which one do you mean, exactly @TeXnician ?

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes you sound like the godfather :D

Comment: I meant your "I will put them `%` everywhere [...]". Ask @egreg about this topic ;)

Comment: I don't know how to "ask specific people" in SE. Is that even possible?

Comment: Then you should read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34844/when-is-it-harmful-to-add-percent-character-at-end-of-lines-in-a-newcommand-or

Comment: You can *reply* to specific people only if they have already commented on the thread, using the @ syntax.  Otherwise, to get someone's attention, you can go to the chat board.  So @egreg will not work at this moment.

Comment: Summon @egreg now

Comment: Thanks for the read. We just received guests and I need to go. It was nice talking to you guys. If anyone cares to provide an answer, I will deal with it tomorrow.

Comment: What would experts say to the following redefinition in the preamble: `\let\origmarginpar\marginpar
\renewcommand{\marginpar}[2][]{\mbox{}\origmarginpar[#1]{#2}}`

Comment: @thymaro See also http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb36-2/tb113gregorio.pdf

Comment: @egreg who is the Grand Wizard? DE Knuth? thanks for the link.

Comment: @thymaro Yes, indeed it is Knuth